# Snow Leopard Server - default version of Apache, and compatibility with Server Admin utility?

Tags: apache, apache2, osx-snow-leopard

According to this page (which refers to Mac OS X Server Panther):

http://macos-x-server.com/wiki/index.php?title=Built-in_Apache_2

"you should be aware that you will not be able to use the Server Admin tool to monitor or administer Apache 2." i.e. Apache 1 is the default, and switching to Apache 2 breaks the usefulness of the Server Admin utility.

Could someone tell me if this is still true with Snow Leopard Server?

i.e. What is the default version of Apache with Snow Leopard Server, and/or is the Server Admin tool compatible with Apache 2?

(I ask because I'm looking to install Passenger with RoR, and that requires Apache 2, but I don't want to break Server Admin functionality)

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've since confirmed that Snow Leopard (and I believe Leopard) does indeed ship with Apache 2 as the default.

As Mythbusters would say 'CONFIRMED'.

No word on whether the Server Admin tools support this, but I have to believe they do.

As Mythbusters would say 'PLAUSIBLE'.

;-)